# Move origin from center to top left corner in Python turtle?

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want the top left corner to be the reference point (0,0) and the origin represented by other coordinates (x>0, y>0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> didn't solve my real problem. i inserted a RawTurtle into a tkinter
>   Canvas. but i could not find the RawTurtle.setworldcoordinates method
>   as i find it in turtle.setworldcoordinates

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = turtle.ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-10, 100, 100, -10)

turtle = turtle.RawTurtle(screen)
turtle.goto(90, 90)

screen.mainloop()
```

You wrap the Tk canvas in a TurtleScreen and create your RawTurtle on that wrapped canvas.  Then you can use `setworldcoordinates()` to manipulate the coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

You can change coordinates using `turtle.setworldcoordinates(llx, lly, urx, ury)`

Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/turtle.html#turtle.setworldcoordinates

Comment: well that works in this situation, but didn't solve my real problem. i inserted a RawTurtle into a tkinter Canvas. but i could not find the RawTurtle.setworldcoordinates method as i find it in turtle.setworldcoordinates